# Duck typing sum in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm learning Haskell and trying to figure out how to implement "duck typing" sum in haskell. So it should be a function, that accepts either char or int, and depending on it either concat or add it.
So function definition should look something like this:
duckplus :: (AddableUnionType a) -> a -> a -> a

```
  duckplus 1 "1" -- "11"
  duckplus 1 1 -- 2
```

Is it possible to use pattern matching?

Comment: usually [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is a runtime/dynamic problem - so Haskell is not the best fit - looking at your example `duckplus 1 "1"` would have type `duckplus :: Num a => a -> String -> b` so you could not have it your type

Comment: you can still do things like this with type-families and associated types - but I would not call it duck-typing

Comment: Your definitions doesn't fit, because it should be possible also to pass duckplus "1" 1 and the result should be "11"

Comment: of course it does not fit - see you wanted `a -> a -> a` and this will never fit neither `Int -> String -> String` nor `String -> Int -> String`

Comment: @Carsten so how to implement it? :) Create a union type :: Addable a => a -> a -> a ?

Comment: no you would have to create a type-class that associates the two input types with the desired output type and includes the `duckplus` function - but this will open a can of nasty worms and it's not really idiomatic haskell

Comment: @Carsten Sure, I know, I just do it for myself to be more familiar with types mechanics in Haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I put the question incorrectly, but it seems, that it can be solved easier, something like this:

```
data IntOrString = Mint Int | Mstr String

plus (Mint a) (Mint b) = show (a + b)
plus (Mint a) (Mstr b) = show a ++ b
plus (Mstr a) (Mint b) = a ++ show b
plus (Mstr a) (Mstr b) = a ++ b

res = plus (Mint 1) (Mint 1) -- 2
res = plus (Mstr "1") (Mint 1) -- 11
```

It requires to wrap Int and String to the constructor values, but doesn't need any externals.

Answer (score 7):

#### caution:

**no-idiomatic Haskell following**

You probably should see this as a demonstration of what Haskells type-system is capable of if you ask it nicely.

For actual work I would not *recommend* a solution like this.

---

here is a possible implementation (with the *can of worms* aka extensions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class DuckSum a b where
  type Result a b :: *
  duckplus :: a -> b -> Result a b

instance DuckSum Int String where
  type Result Int String = String
  duckplus a b = show a ++ b

instance DuckSum String Int where
  type Result String Int = String
  duckplus a b = a ++ show b

instance DuckSum Int Int where
  type Result Int Int = Int
  duckplus a b = a+b
```

here is an interactive session using this:

```
λ> duckplus (1 :: Int) "1"
"11"
λ> duckplus "1" (1 :: Int)
"11"
λ> duckplus (1 :: Int) (1 :: Int)
2
```

**note** that you need the type-annotations here as `1` could be any `Num` - also use with care

Comment: Alternatively, use `data Expr = EInt Int | EString String` and provide the `Num` (for `fromIntegral`) and `IsString` (for `-XOverloadedStrings`) instances. Still going to be fun, since `Num` is likely partial.

Comment: @Zeta this should probably be another answer ;)

Comment: Great, thank you. Now it's more clear for me how to use type classes

Comment: @RaxWunter well the magic here are the associated types that come with type-families - the class is just to *overload*  `duckplus` ;) - glad to help out

Comment: @Carsten and are there any options to do it without extensions?

Comment: that what @Zeta hinted at - in this case you would have an `Expr` ADT and make use of the fact that integer-literals are used with `fromIntegral` - but you would need an extension to add this for `String`s as well (`OverloadedStrings`) - aside from this no - I don't think so - aside from the `TypeSynonymInstances` those are perfectly fine with most Haskellers - indeed you'll see the `FlexibleInstances` and `MultiParamTypeClasses` almost everywhere ;)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner so how I should? As I said, task is specific one, I'm just curious with Haskell type capabilities

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I hope I have not offended - want me to add an disclaimer of sorts (aside form the small warning)?

Comment: @Carsten No, not offended, just amused. You might want to add that this is not idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: @RaxWunter: I guess one reply would be ”What problem are you trying to solve?” and figure out a Haskellish way of doing it. (At least if the problem is not “playing around with the type system”, which is of course a valid thing to do.)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I actually did in one of the comments that led to the answer - but I'll add the warning ^^